# Remove an event handler

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I've added an event like so:

```
this.getLetters().element.on({
   tap: me.lettersTap,
   delegate: 'span.letter-hidden'
});
```

based on user interaction, I'm adding another class to those 
elements, so it will be:

```
<span class="letter-hidden new_class">
```

I want to remove the event handler based on the "new_class",but got no clue how.
I tried like:

```
questionController.getLetters().element.un({
            tap: questionController.lettersTap,
            delegate: 'span.new_class',
            scope: questionController
        });
```

but it's not working, I am able to remove it if I replace the "new_class" with letter-hidden in the above code, so I suppose works to be removed if the same class is used, which is not mentioned in documentation. Am I doing something wrong, an alternative would be nice to have it...Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a delegate so it would be important to use exactly the same when you are trying to remove it. Otherwise ExtJS must expect it is a different element, which is a correct behavior.

This is how the registered listeners get checked:

```
(registered.fn === remove.fn && 
 registered.scope === remove.scope && 
 registered.delegate === remove.delegate && 
 registered.order === remove.order)
```

So no, there is no alternative way. You have to unregister with the same properties as you registered it.

> **Note**: Sencha don't use your properties to query within the DOM it just
>   lookup in the oberservalbe listeners collection for a listener that
>   was registered like the one you handed to unregister.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was hopping to get. Now I understand, I searched the source code but I didn't saw this ...I ended up replacing the class of the element and the listener is gone too. Thanks.